# PHP/HTML appears and functions in Source view but not in browser?

Tags: php, html, href, html-table

I have a bit of my code that seems to work in source view, but doesn't appear in my browser?

It's a link within a table being generated by PHP echo. It looks like this in Source:

```
<td><a href=http://www.webaddresshere.com></a></td>
```

The code generating it is:

```
<td><a href=<?php echo htmlentities($row['website'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></td>
```

And here is the full table it is within:

```
    <h3>Listings</h3>
<table cellpadding="10%" cellspacing="10%" width="100%">
<tbody align="left">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['supplier'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['service'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['price'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td><a href=http://<?php echo htmlentities($row['website'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>></a></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['telephone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><br></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Any ideas as to why it's doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Add some text into hyper link.

Comment: The anchors are empty, you need add some content for the browser to make a visible link.

Comment: <td><a href=<?php echo htmlentities($row['website'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>Your Text</a></td>

Comment: Sidenote: Remember to use quotes around your `href`s. It's just good HTML practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is no text in your link, so basically, nothing is being linked.

```
<td><a href=<?php echo htmlentities($row['website'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>Some Text Here For It To Be Clickable</a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks,

I thought for some reason that leaving that blank made the actual address appear as the link, will just make that the htmlentities thing too!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Look here -

```
<td><a href=http://www.webaddresshere.com></a></td>
------------------------------------------^
```

There is no text in the link.

Comment: We should be hearing the sound of a "facepalm", very soon.

Comment: Heh...it's still early, we might get to hear enough to generate an applause like sound.

Comment: *...and the crowd went wild!*

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3>Listings</h3>
<table cellpadding="10%" cellspacing="10%" width="100%">
    <tbody align="left">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Supplier</th>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Website</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['supplier'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['service'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['price'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td><a href="http://<?php echo htmlentities($row['website'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">Link</a></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['telephone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Check here I added one text 'Link', which should be visible to click :).